# Blazor redirect on policy failed

Tags: authorization, blazor, blazor-webassembly

I need to react differently based on which authorization policy failed. So, if PolicyA failed when user tried to navigate to pageA (which requires PolicyA), I would like to redirect to pageB.

Is this possible in Blazor WASM?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option is to use `IAuthorizationService` and the cascaded parameter of type `Task<AuthenticationState>` like this:

```
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization
@inject IAuthorizationService AuthorizationService
@inject NavigationManager NavigationManager

...

@code {
    [CascadingParameter]
    private Task<AuthenticationState> authenticationStateTask { get; set; }

    protected async override Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        var user = (await authenticationStateTask).User;

        if ((await AuthorizationService.AuthorizeAsync(user, "PolicyA"))
            .Succeeded)
        {
            NavigationManager.NavigateTo("pageB");
        }

        // rest of the code
    }
}
```

Another option is to use `AuthorizeView` component like this:

```
@inject NavigationManager NavigationManager

<AuthorizeView Policy="PolicyA">
    <Authorized>
        @* Page content *@
    </Authorized>
    <NotAuthorized>
        @{ Navigation.NavigateTo("pageB"); }
    </NotAuthorized>
</AuthorizeView>

@code {

}
```